# How to apply operations on each array item in a column in Presto?

Tags: python, sql, presto, trino

We want to check if the array items in text_array column start with "a" in the input table, and store the results into the third column, so we get the following output table.

[image]

My first question is: Is there any way to get output table from input table using presto?

In python we can define a function for it, like:

```
def myFunc(text):
    out = []
    for word in text:
        out.append(word.startswith("a"))
    return out
```

My second question is: Is there any way to use the python function with presto? I was looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  text_array,
  myFunc(text_array) AS starts_with_a
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform) from [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html):

```sql
- sample data
with dataset(id, text_array) AS (
 values (1, array['ax', 'by']),
    (2, array['ax', 'ay', 'cz'])
)

-- query
select *,
    transform(text_array, el -> el like 'a%') starts_with_a
from dataset;
```

Output:

| id | text_array | starts_with_a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ax, by] | [true, false] |
| 2 | [ax, ay, cz] | [true, true, false] |